# Referencing the tooltip-content html tag from the parent

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement ngx-tooltip in angular 8 application.  I have a parent component and two child components. There are several 
buttons on the child component that need the same toolip to be displayed. I dont want to duplicate the code everywhere and rather
have it on one place

For e.g

the child component has the following html for the button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-margin-right-5" triggers="pointerenter:pointerout" tooltip="myTooltip" [disabled]="true" (click)="validateAndGetQuote(f.form.valid)">
                        <i *ngIf="isQuoteLoading" class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> {{ isQuoteLoading ? 'Quoting...' : isRequote ? 'Requote' : 'Get Quote' }}
 </button>
```

If i ever to use the below template, is there a way to have it the parent and referenced in the child component html

```
<tooltip-content #myTooltip [animation]="true" placement="bottom">
                    <b>Very</b> <span style="color: #C21F39">Dynamic</span> <span style="color: #00b3ee">Reusable</span>
                    <b><i><span style="color: #ffc520">Tooltip With</span></i></b> <small>Html support</small>.
                </tooltip-content>
```

Comment: Do i need to use ng-template and if yes how do i use it in this scenario ?

Comment: Allow me to suggest you take a look at two options: [@angular/cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) and the one I prefer: [North Carolina State University Popover](https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover)